# how to skip empty rdd when join in spark

Tags: join, dictionary, cassandra, apache-spark, flatmap

I want to get 2 rdd from Cassandra,then join them.And I want to skip the empty value.

```
def extractPair(rdd: RDD[CassandraRow]) = {
    rdd.map((row: CassandraRow) => {

     val name = row.getName("name")
     if (name == "")
         None   //join wrong
     else
        (name, row.getUUID("object"))

    })
  }

  val rdd1 = extractPair(cassRdd1)
  val rdd2 = extractPair(cassRdd2)
  val joinRdd = rdd1.join(rdd2)  //"None" join wrong
```

use flatMap can fix this,but i want to know how to use map fix this

```
def extractPair(rdd: RDD[CassandraRow]) = {
        rdd.flatMap((row: CassandraRow) => {

         val name = row.getName("name")
         if (name == "")
             seq()
         else
            Seq((name, row.getUUID("object")))

        })
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible with just a `map`. You would need to follow it up with a `filter`. But you would still be best to wrap the valid result in a `Some`. But, then you would still have it wrapped in a Some as a result...requiring a second `map` to unwrap it. So, realistically, your best option is something like this:

```
def extractPair(rdd: RDD[CassandraRow]) = {
  rdd.flatMap((row: CassandraRow) => {
    val name = row.getName("name")
    if (name == "") None
    else Some((name, row.getUUID("object")))
  })
}
```

`Option` is implicitly convertable to a flattenable type and conveys your methods message better.

Comment: this is woring.  Value join is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Some[(Any, java.util.UUID)]]

Comment: Are you using `flatMap`? It should strip away the `Some`

Comment: What i have given flatMap Code could work,but i what to know how to use map.Because i think map is efficient than flatMap.

Comment: And what makes you think that map is more efficient? I addressed your map question in the first section of my answer...did you even read that? Or just try to copy the code?

Comment: yeah,i have read your advice,but i do not understand.  Map is used to input one output one, FlatMap is used to input one output many.So i think Map is more efficient.

Comment: No, as you know flatmap is one to zero or more. You cannot do what you want in map alone. Thus why flatMap is the best option